# Should I put the group email address that already exists?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I'm creating a group for the organization from IAM & Admin. There is a "Group email address" input box, but I don't know what kind of email address they are asking for. Should I put a group email address that already being used? Or is this for the new email address that GCP will create? If so, when and how can I use this new email address?

[image: Create Group]

Comment: Accordingly to the documentation [Creating a group](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/groups-in-cloud-console): "*3. **Fill in your group's details, including** the group's name, **email address**, and an optional description*". So, it's expected that you should provide some new email address for your new group. Does it answer your question?

Comment: If you already have a group you should follow [Viewing and editing group details](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/groups-in-cloud-console#viewing-editing-details).

Comment: If you use [Google Workspace](https://workspace.google.com/) you can follow [this doc](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33329?hl=en).

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza Does the `new email address` mean an email address that is not added in GCP, but being used by the organization(company)? I made a group with a random email address and sent a test mail to it, but I got a `no mailbox` error. I'm confused.

Comment: Do you use Google Workspace (G Suite) or Google Cloud Identity? Please add screenshots.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza I'm using GCP IAM & Admin. Added a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks. Could you share an error message as well?

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza The Error message is from the company's mail server after I sent an email: `I'm afraid I wasn't able to deliver your message to the following addresses.
This is a permanent error; I've given up. Sorry it didn't work out. Recipient: <masked email address> Reason: <masked IPv4 address> does not like recipient. Remote host said: 550 sorry, no mailbox (#5.7.1) Giving up on <masked IPv4 address>.`

Comment: *The group email address it's only an identificator*, same as an email address of the service account. You can use this email address for granting roles and permissions. Why are you trying to send an email to the group email address?

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza I just wanted to know how the email works. There was no explanation, so I did a trial and error. So, it seems the group email address is not for that. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please describe you use case? What have you expected from the group address? Do you want to grant same permissions to the group of people or do you need an alias to send email to the group of people?

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza I want to group our developers so I can easily manage their roles and permissions as a group. But I don't know what should I put in the group email address. Is this just some kind of ID?

Comment: In this case it's the right way to go. Create groups for different roles, grant permissions to the groups and add developer to the groups to grant necessary permissions to them.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza So, the email address is just some kind of ID? Can I put whatever I want?

Comment: Yes, it's an ID that looks like an email.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza That answers my question. Thank you!

Comment: I posted an answer. Please accept/upvote it if my explanation was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me summarize our discussion at the comment section. [Let's start with IAM Overview](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview) where at the section [Google group](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#google_group) you can see:

> A Google group is a named collection of Google Accounts and service accounts. *Every Google group has a unique email address that's associated with the group.* You can find the email address that's associated with a Google group by clicking About on the homepage of any Google group. For more information about Google Groups, see the [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/) homepage.
>
> *Google Groups are a convenient way to apply an access policy to a collection of users.* You can grant and change access controls for a whole group at once instead of granting or changing access controls one at a time for individual users or service accounts. *You can also easily add members to and remove members from a Google group instead of updating an IAM policy to add or remove users.*

More information you can find at the documentation page [Managing groups in the Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/groups-in-cloud-console), for example instructions how to [create](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/groups-in-cloud-console#creating), [edit](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/groups-in-cloud-console#viewing-editing-details) or [delete](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/groups-in-cloud-console#deleting) a group.

*Group email address is a unique identifier* in form of the email address, similar concept you can see for a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating) such as `sa-name@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com`.